# Consulta yii2 mysql

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

estoy intentando hacer una consulta en yii2, soy nuevo y aun no me he familiarizado bien con el tema de consultas, la consulta es la siguiente:

necesito traer estos datos:

```
->select('ingreso.idingreso', 'ingreso.fecha_hora', 'persona.nombre', 'ingreso.tipo_comprobante', 'ingreso.serie_comprobante', 'ingreso.num_comprobante', 'ingreso.impuesto', 'ingreso.estado', 'SUM("ingreso.cantidad*precio_cantidad") AS total')
```

Esto es lo que intente pero no funcionó, ya intente con varios tipos de join:

```
$table = Ingreso::find()
                    ->leftJoin('persona', 'ingreso.idingreso = persona.idpersona')
                    ->leftJoin('detalle_ingreso', 'ingreso.idingreso = detalle_ingreso.idingreso')
                    ->select('ingreso.idingreso', 'ingreso.fecha_hora', 'persona.nombre', 'ingreso.tipo_comprobante', 'ingreso.serie_comprobante', 'ingreso.num_comprobante', 'ingreso.impuesto', 'ingreso.estado', 'SUM("ingreso.cantidad*precio_cantidad") AS total')
                    ->Where(["estado" => 'A'])                                         
                    ->orderBy(['ingreso.idingreso' => SORT_DESC])
                    ->groupBy(['ingreso.idingreso', 'ingreso.fecha_hora', 'persona.nombre', 'ingreso.tipo_comprobante', 'ingreso.serie_comprobante', 'ingreso.num_comprobante', 'ingreso.impuesto', 'ingreso.estado']);
            $pages = new Pagination([
                                "pageSize" => 4,
                                "totalCount" => $table->count()
                                ]);
            $model = $table
                    ->limit($pages->limit)
                    ->all();
```

Mis tablas son estas:
[image: Tabla personas]

[image: Tabla ingreso]

[image: Tabla detalle_ingreso]

Aparte de eso me arroja un erro con la paginación en esta parte:

```
"totalCount" => $table->count()
```

Les agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: cual es el mensaje de error?? tenes creado los modelos de todas tus tablas?? te suguiero que pruebes hacer consultas simples, y luego con las uniones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desde mi punto de vista la primera casa que veo  mal es que estas hacienod una consulta de tipo de datos "Ingreso" por lo que la respuesta de tu consulta deveria sera un tipo de coleccione de objetos tipo "ingreso" , pero como puedes ver en tu consulta estas metiendo diferentes tablas como "persona " o incluso haces operaciones de SUM , si tu necesitas hacer algo así no te recomiendo que utilices el Model::find().

Con algo aprecido a esto deberia  serte mas util y creo seria la manera correcta

```
$query = new Query;
// compose the query
$query->->leftJoin('persona', 'ingreso.idingreso = persona.idpersona')
                ->leftJoin('detalle_ingreso', 'ingreso.idingreso = detalle_ingreso.idingreso')
                ->select('ingreso.idingreso', 'ingreso.fecha_hora', 'persona.nombre', 'ingreso.tipo_comprobante', 'ingreso.serie_comprobante', 'ingreso.num_comprobante', 'ingreso.impuesto', 'ingreso.estado', 'SUM("ingreso.cantidad*precio_cantidad") AS total')
                ->Where(["estado" => 'A'])                                         
                ->orderBy(['ingreso.idingreso' => SORT_DESC])
                ->groupBy(['ingreso.idingreso', 'ingreso.fecha_hora', 'persona.nombre', 'ingreso.tipo_comprobante', 'ingreso.serie_comprobante', 'ingreso.num_comprobante', 'ingreso.impuesto', 'ingreso.estado']);
// build and execute the query
$rows = $query->all();
```

Para lo de la paginacion te recomiendo que leas la docummetacion official sobre ello , aqui tienes un pequeño ejemplo

```
$query = Article::find()->where(['status' => 1]); // puedes substituir esta lina por l o anteriormente explicado 
$countQuery = clone $query;
$pages = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $countQuery->count()]);
$models = $query->offset($pages->offset)
        ->limit($pages->limit)
        ->all();




foreach ($models as $model) {
    // display $model here
}

// display pagination
echo LinkPager::widget([
    'pagination' => $pages,
]);
```

Documentación de paginación Yii2 :http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-pagination.html

Answer (score -1):

Falta terminar la instruccion **find()->...** con el comando **...->all();** ó **...->one()**

Ejemplo:

```
$table = Ingreso::find()
                ->leftJoin('persona', 'ingreso.idingreso = persona.idpersona')
                ->leftJoin('detalle_ingreso', 'ingreso.idingreso = detalle_ingreso.idingreso')
                ->select('ingreso.idingreso', 'ingreso.fecha_hora', 'persona.nombre', 'ingreso.tipo_comprobante', 'ingreso.serie_comprobante', 'ingreso.num_comprobante', 'ingreso.impuesto', 'ingreso.estado', 'SUM("ingreso.cantidad*precio_cantidad") AS total')
                ->Where(["estado" => 'A'])                                         
                ->orderBy(['ingreso.idingreso' => SORT_DESC])
                ->groupBy(['ingreso.idingreso', 'ingreso.fecha_hora', 'persona.nombre', 'ingreso.tipo_comprobante', 'ingreso.serie_comprobante', 'ingreso.num_comprobante', 'ingreso.impuesto', 'ingreso.estado'])
                ->all();
```

Comment: Evita poner links (se terminan rompiendo). Y da una explicacion mas detallada. De esta manera siempre sera una respuesta completa. Echale un vistazo a [answer].